# htaccess Mod_rewrite with accents

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, diacritics

I have an international website, and a section of the website, used to create a new person, has the person's name in the URL. I need that URL to allow accents as well as some special characters like à

Right now I'm using:

```
RewriteRule ^([áéíóúñÁÉÍÓÚÑäëïöüÄËÏÖÜçÇA-Za-z-]+)/?$ /newPerson.php?person=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

UPDATE:
This works, but is not a very elegant approach. I am asking for a better way of matching all letters (lower and uppercase) with all possible accents à, á, ä... etc, if there is such a thing.

UPDATE 2:
There is no apparent way to indicate in a regexp "a character and all its accented versions" so I think I'll stick with this...

Comment: Why don't you encode the query string?http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I might do this, but I would need to allow numbers and that would conflict with another rule...

Answer (score 2):

You could just allow anything except e.g. `/` `.`. Regex uses the `[^ ]`-notation for this. In your case you could use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /newPerson.php?person=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: I think this conflicts with another rule because it generates an internal server error, as well as using (.*)

Comment: Could you add the other rules to your question?