# French characters with rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have categories name in my database, and some of theme have french characters like é è ê.
It works as desired until today when I tried to add another character à to it then I started getting SERVER ERROR

Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9éèêà_-\s]+)-(\d+)\.htm$   classified.php?id=$2 [L]
```

As you can see, it works fine without the à.

How do I add that thing into the regex ?

Comment: Check this: [htaccess Mod\_rewrite with accents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451601/htaccess-mod-rewrite-with-accents). In fact, it seems impossible to put accented character inside a .htaccess.

Comment: The [Apache docs on `mod_rewrite`'s `b` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) should help you with this.

Comment: why not using [^accented]? I think its better for some cases

Comment: Aren't accents/foreign characters in urls typically shunned at (unless after ?'s) because its hard for some users to input it if they are typing it by hand into a browser/don't have a foreign keyboard that can easily input those characters/etc.

Comment: Not a duplicate but worth considering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386262/should-i-use-accented-characters-in-urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using all sort of characters and accented letters, then why don't just allow anything to go by?

NOTE: Using this Rule will also allow spaces;

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(\d+)\.htm$   classified.php?id=$2 [L]
```

And later if you decide to limit the regex, lets say you don't want any of these characters # $ % then you have to make exceptions:

```
   Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^([^#$%]+)-(\d+)\.htm$   classified.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like extended ASCII characters in URL are sent as UTF-8 and url-encoded. For example:

```
/éèêà-1.htm -> /%C3%A9%C3%A8%C3%AA%C3%A0-1.htm
```

The above URL can be matched by mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:\w|\xC3\xA9|\xC3\xA8|\xC3\xAA|\xC3\xA0)+-(\d+)\.htm$ classified.php?id=$1 [L]
```