# Rewrite url rule with french accents

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a URL with french accents to another URL without them.

Not sure what I am missing because it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/content\/dam\/gwl\/documents\/s7\_000336fr\_Donnéesfinancières\.pdf$

RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/vous-et-votre-famille/formulaires/formulaires-de-demande-de-reglement-de-regimes-collectifs/formulaires-de-demande-de-reglement-standards.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What is original URL that you're trying to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so:

```
RewriteRule ^_Donn%C3%A9esfinanci%C3%A8res(.*)$ http://www.example.fr/_donneesfinancieres.html [L,R=301]
```

Another way is under [.htaccess - How to redirect uppercase and accented letters to unaccented lowercase in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464217/htaccess-how-to-redirect-uppercase-and-accented-letters-to-unaccented-lowerca)